# apt-get won't work

Tags: apt, 13.04, laptop, bumblebee

I installed the latest updates from update manger and `apt-get` won't work.  I think it has something to do with bumblebee/primusrun due to this error output:

```
    installArchives() failed: Setting up install-info (4.13a.dfsg.1-10ubuntu4) ...
    /etc/environment: line 1: $'=\342\200\235primusrun\342\200\235': command not found
    dpkg: error processing install-info (--configure):
    subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 127
    No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
    Errors were encountered while processing:
        install-info
    Setting up install-info (4.13a.dfsg.1-10ubuntu4) ...
    /etc/environment: line 1: $'=\342\200\235primusrun\342\200\235': command not found
    dpkg: error processing install-info (--configure):
    subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 127
```

I am using a dell XPS laptop with Ubuntu 13.04.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have copied instructions from some blog without paying attention. Perhaps you have a line such as the following in your `/etc/environment` file:

```
foo =”primusrun”
```

Try removing that line and run `sudo apt-get install -f` to continue the installation.

Comment: removing the stuff i had set for steam did fix it... weird

Comment: No other package should touch `/etc/environment` except for the package providing that file. Perhaps you can copy the contents of that file and paste it into your question?