# Preparing to replace install-info 4.13a.dfsg.1-10ubuntu4 (using .../install-info_5.1.dfsg.1-3_i386.deb)

Tags: installation, package-management

When I upgraded my system, I had a problem about this syntax:

```
Preparing to replace install-info 4.13a.dfsg.1-10ubuntu4 (using .../install-info_5.1.dfsg.1-3_i386.deb) ...
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/install-info_5.1.dfsg.1-3_i386.deb (--unpack):
triggers ci file contains unknown directive `interest-noawait'
Errors were encountered while processing:
/var/cache/apt/archives/install-info_5.1.dfsg.1-3_i386.deb

E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Can anybody help me with this problem?

Comment: Your error message is not unique. In fact there is an accepted answer to a question containing a similar error message about 4.13a.dfsg.1-10ubuntu4 [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/294490/apt-get-wont-work).

Answer (score 2):

Run `sudo apt-get install dpkg` before running anything else. It seems that the package in question depends on a newer version of dpkg, but doesn't list that dependency.

See http://lists.debian.org/debian-tex-maint/2013/05/msg00373.html for more info.